# Why Math.Round() works differently in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

First I noticed that `Math.Round()` doesn't round for 2 digits as I as for:

```
double dd = Math.Round(1.66666, 2);
```

Result:

```
dd = 1.6699999570846558;
```

and then I created a new project with same .NET framework and the result is `1.67` now as it should been in the first place.

I've never seen `Round` behaving like this before, what is causing this problem?

Comment: Not this question again. [Please read the following](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The problem is you are using an imprecise numerical type to represent an exact value. If you want exact decimal values, use `decimal`. For a minute there I almost thought this was going to be the old "Banker's Rounding" issue.

Comment: double? The fact that you, as a prorammer, have avoided learning how floating point numbers work. WHich means you lack a fundamental understanding what you do - much like a cook wondering that the oven gets hot when he turns it on.

Comment: Floating-point numbers get rounded off to... floating point numbers. Either live with that fact and display the number in an appropriate format, or use the `decimal` type.

Comment: Or for a more easily accessible version of the sort of info at @presiuslitelsnoflek's link, see http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find this question asked previously here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the other comments mentioned, use `decimal` to hold the returned value:

```
decimal dd = Math.Round(1.66666M, 2);
```

The issue you described has nothing to do with the `Round()` function. You can read a bit about how the floating point numbers & fixed point numbers work, but the short explanation is:

With floating point variables (e.g. `double`), you cannot guarantee the precision of the number you save it them. So when you save something like 1.67 in a variable of the type `double` and then you check the value later on, therer is no guarantee you will get exactly 1.67. You may get a value like 1.66999999 (similar to what you got) or like 1.6700000001.

Fixed point variables (e.g. `decimal`) on the other hand, will give you that precision, so if you save 1.67, you will always get 1.67 back.

Please note that the `Round()` function returns the same type that you pass to it, so to make return a `decimal`, you need to pass it **1.66666M** which is a decimal value rather than 1.66666 which is a floating point number.

Comment: @Weston Thanks for the observation. I was focused on the explanation rather than the code, because it was obvious that the OP was just testing things and he needed an explanation rather than code. I updated my answer, though, just for the sake of correctness. And I added a note about the `Round()` function.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!